# How to use cb_obj in callbacks in bokeh?

Tags: javascript, bokehjs

In `bokeh.models.actions.Action`, there is a `callback` class for user defined callback. It passes the current `plot_object` as `cb_obj` implicitly.

However, I don't know how to access the data from the `plot_object`.

```js
    fig = figure()
    fig.circle(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6])
    tap_tool.action = Callback(
        code="""
            alert('clicked')
            console.log(cb_obj)

        """)
```

How can I access the information, e.g. x, y of a clicked circle? In a template string we can use `@variable` or `$x` to get information about each data point.

Furthermore, it seems to me that there is only 1 `Circle Glyph`, despite of 3 circles. So glyph has nothing to do with the number of data points, is it correct?

Does `cb_obj` refer to this `Glyph`, or the `glyphRenderer` that contains this glyph?

In the docs an example shows:

```js
    var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
    var d1 = cb_obj.get('data');
```

Where does `select, id, indices, data` come from? What's the structure of `cb_obj`.

Answer (score 2):

As of Bokeh 0.9.0, for `TapTool` actions, the value of `cb_obj` is the data source for the glyph that reported the hit. This example shows how to access the data columns:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-tools

Answer (score 1):

You can actually inspect the object through:

```
console.log(cb_data);
console.log(cb_obj);
```

For example use this callbacks to inspect the contents of both object:

```
scode = """
        console.log(cb_obj);
        console.log(cb_data);
        """
taptool.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),code = scode)
```

If you run in chrome you will see the content of cb_obj and cb_data in your logs (View-Developer-Javascripts Console)